# Implementing Caesar Cipher in C

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I am trying to implement a "Caeser cipher" to every lower case character in a string, by using a number to control the amount of character rotation. Here is an algorithm that I came up with. Can you please review and give me some feedback?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char string4[80];
    int  rotatorN;

    printf("Enter String: ");
    gets(string4);
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%i", &rotatorN);

    int n = 0, rotateSwap = 0;

    int i;
    for(i=0; string4[i] != '\0'; i++)
     {
          if(string4[i] >='a' && string4[i] <='z')
             {
                n = 'z' - string4[i];
                if( rotatorN > n )
                 {
                    rotateSwap = rotatorN - n - 1;
                    string4[i] = 'a';
                    string4[i] += rotateSwap;
                  }  
               else
                string4[i] += rotatorN;


               }
       }

      int j;
      for(j = 0; string4[j] !='\0'; j++)
        {
             printf("%c", string4[j]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some observations that may help you improve this code.

### Don't use `gets`

Using `gets` is not good practice because it can lead to buffer overruns.  It has been removed from the C11 standard and marked "obsolete" in POSIX 2008.  Use `fgets` instead, or in this case, you could simply pass in the string as a command line parameter.  Alternatively, you could have the number passed in as a command line option and the string could be read from `stdin` which would allow use of the program as a pipe.

### Check return values for errors

The call to `scanf` can fail.  You can check the return values to make sure they haven't or your program may crash (or worse) when given malformed input or due to low system resources.  Rigorous error handling is the difference between mostly working versus bug-free software.  You should strive for the latter.

### Consinder signed versus unsigned

The variable `rotatorN` is declared as an `int` which is a signed quantity and the `scanf` function will allow a user to enter a negative number such as -99.  However, the program does not produce useful output in that case, so it would be better to restrict the value to positive numbers.  In fact, it would probably make sense to restrict it to the range of 0 to 25 inclusive, assuming an ASCII string (more on that later).

### Consider separating I/O from the algorithm

Right now, everything is done in main.  Better practice is to separate things into functions.  In particular, I'd recommend separating the input/output routines from the actual cipher.

### Use better variable names

The variable name `rotatorN` is good, but the name `string4` is not.  The first name explains something about what the variable means within the context of the code, but the latter is only confusing. A better name might be `plaintext`.

### Know what the C standard *doesn't* say

Your code makes the assumption that all lowercase letters are linearly organized in the range of `'a'` to `'z'`, but that's only true of ASCII.  The C standard doesn't have such a requirement, and in fact, on a machine using EBCDIC encoding, your code would fail.

### Use pointers rather than indexing for speed

Your program probably doesn't need a lot of speed, but you should know that using indexing is generally slower than using a pointer.  In a loop such as the main one in your program, the increase in speed could be considerable for a very long string.

### Don't use `printf` where it isn't needed

Your code uses an odd loop to print the translated string, calling `printf` with a format string of `"%c"`.  Rather than using that, use `putchar()` or better still, replace the entire loop with `puts()`.

### Eliminate `return 0`

You don't need to explicitly provide a `return 0;` at the end of main -- it's created implicitly by the compiler.

### Consider an alternative approach

Rather than doing all of that calculation for each letter, you could use a simple lookup mechanism instead.  Keep two contiguous alphabets in memory and use the plaintext char and rotate value to calculate an offset.  Here's a complete program with most of these ideas incorporated, but note that it still won't work correctly with EBCDIC or a locale other than C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ALPHABET_LEN 26

int encode(int ch, int rotate)
{
    const char alphabet[2*ALPHABET_LEN] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if (islower(ch)) {
        return alphabet[ch-'a'+rotate];
    } else {
        return ch;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("Usage: caesar rotateN\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int rotatorN = atoi(argv[1]) % ALPHABET_LEN;

    for (int ch = getchar(); ch != EOF; ch = getchar()) {
            putchar(encode(ch, rotatorN));
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
$ echo the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog | ./caesar -1
sgd pthbj aqnvm enw itlodc nudq sgd kyx cnf
```

Comment: I find it a bit awkward that you're defining a constant `ALPHABET_LENGTH` that cannot be changed without also changing a hardcoded string elsewhere. At the very least, there should be a comment about that; even better, you could do `#define ALPHABET "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` right next to it (and `const char alphabet[2*ALPHABET_LEN] = ALPHABET ALPHABET;` later). Also, you seem to be spending considerable effort to avoid the `%` operator, but then use it anyway in `main()`. And if you're avoiding `%` and worrying about EBCDIC, why not go the last step and use `strchr()` instead of `ch-'a'`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: For the `%` operator, note that is only used exactly once, regardless of input string length. Also instead of using `strchr()`, I'd probably instead dyamically construct a translation table to use as a map, but that would be a more significant change to the original.

Answer (score 8):

You should never use `gets()` to read keyboard input, *ever*. Use `fgets()`, where you specify the max size of the buffer. That way, you are protecting yourself from somebody hacking your code.

You don't check input values. It is good practice to not assume a benevolent keyboard user, so, for instance, when a user enters `rotatorN = -12128`, you get all kinds of interesting behavior in your program.

Using `scanf` for input is hard to get right and therefore error-prone. Instead, use `fgets` for all input and then use `sscanf` to get the contents.

Check the calculated value for `rotateSwap` so that it falls within the expected range.

Answer (score 6):

- Did they already mentioned `gets`? If not, I'd reiterate: Don't use `gets`. It makes your code vulnerable to buffer overflow; besides, it is deprecated. If your compiler didn't warn you, consider upgrading.
- Don't be shy of functions. Your `main` does too much: it deals with input, encryption and output all at once. Decompose it into single responsibility units.
- `string4` is a very unnerving name. The reviewer immediately starts worrying: *where is `string3`? did I miss it?*.

  I would also consider renaming `rotatorN` and `rotateSwap` (the former is an encryption key - why not call it so?; the latter is a verb - a good name for a function perhaps, but not for a variable).

Answer (score 2):

A few minor things not already mentioned:

- Try to maintain consistent indentation.  It can really help for maintaining readability.
- Add a `void` parameter for `main()` so that the C compiler will know that it doesn't take command line arguments (or any arguments for other functions in general).
- The first two outputs can use [`puts()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm) instead.  It's really only necessary to use `printf()` for formatted output, such as the one in your last `for` loop.

I think it bears repeating: always use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`.  The latter is only still around to prevent breaking of existing code, and even Unix's man page explicitly warns about its use.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK. But, just consider the case when `rotatorN` is greater than 26. Say, for example, `rotatorN` is 100 and `string4` is "a".

Then for the first iteration:

```
n = 'z' - 'a' = 25
rotateSwap = 100 - 25 - 1 = 74
string4[0] = string4[0] + 74 = 97 + 74 = 171,
```

171 is a part of the extended ASCII set and is not exactly what you expected.

In order avoid this issue, you have take the modulus of `rotatorN`. For instance, just after reading `rotatorN`, perform `rotatorN = rotatorN % 26`.